# I have duplicate jar in reference libraries

Tags: android, android-library

I have a duplicate jar file in reference library, is the reason for error multiple dex error?
How can I delete those from reference library

Answer (score 0):

If you are having a `Jar` file with same name in your project and 1 of your referenced libraries, just remove 1 of them. Delete from libs.

Comment: I have same issue my scenario is like i'm using same jar in multiple components and integrating  into single project. How to avoid the jar duplication issue.

Comment: it is called JAR hell